# How can I make several 2D objects move in complex pre-defined patterns?

Tags: unity, movement, logic

I will be making my mobile 2D game in Unity and the objects in the game will have complicated movement. For example, there will be lots of squares (around 10-15 tiny squares) in the middle of the screen which will move in pre-defined patterns like in the shape of an X or an M or O. The tiny squares forming the pattern M will be constantly moving within that X symbol and will be constantly instantiated at one end and destroyed at the other to achieve the effect (or just allowed to move within a pattern if the patterns shape permits).

Unity tutorials explain the basics on how to work with the transform component, etc but I have been looking for a resource that tells you how to achieve the above. How can I implement it?

Comment: Maybe you should look at HOTween: http://hotween.demigiant.com/. It's free, simple to use and allow you to animate of lot of property fields like vectors. You can define Sequence to create more complex animations.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere and emailed the creator but since you have been using this, can I just ask whether dotween will work with 2d paths? thanks